# condensation of mixture of gases

Tags: pressure, gas, condensation

Suppose we take two gases in a vessel with a movable piston.
We compress the mixture until first drop of condensate appears. Knowing just the composition of the mixture in vapor form, can we calculate the composition of the first drop of condensate?

Comment: This is not possible, for similar reasons as Maxwell's daemon cannot exists. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_demon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose temperature remains constant during compression. Therefore when you compress, pressure increases. Condensate will form at a given temperature, when partial pressure of a gas becomes equal to its saturation pressure at that temperature (for example, for water, refer steam tables). Let $p_1,p_2$ be partial pressure of the two gases. Assuming they obey ideal gas equation, we have,
\begin{align}
p_1 & =N_1\frac{RT}{V} \\
p_2 & =N_2\frac{RT}{V} \\ \\
\therefore~\frac{p_1}{p_2} & = \frac{N_1}{N_2}
\end{align}
In the above $p_1,p_2$ change because $V$ changes, but their ratio remains constant.

Let $e_1,e_2$ be their saturation vapor pressures at temperature $T$. In general $e_1\neq e_2$.

Condensation occurs when either $p_1=e_1$ or $p_2=e_2$ or both. If you arrange the number of moles of each gas to be in the ratio $\frac{N_1}{N_2}=\frac{e_1}{e_2}$, then both gases will reach their saturation pressure simultaneously and both of them will condense. If this is not the case then the gas to condense first is the one that will reach its saturation pressure first. Equivalently if $V_1,V_2$ are volumes at which each gas separately reaches its saturation pressure then
\begin{align}
V_1 & =\frac{N_1}{e_1}RT \\
V_2 & =\frac{N_2}{e_2}RT \\ \\
\therefore~\frac{V_1}{V_2} & = \frac{N_1}{N_2}\frac{e_2}{e_1}
\end{align}

Depending on value of $\frac{e_1}{e_2},\frac{N_1}{N_2}$, we can have different values for $\frac{V_1}{V_2}$. If $\frac{V_1}{V_2}>1$ then gas 1 will condense first, and if $\frac{V_1}{V_2}<1$ gas 2 will condense first. If $\frac{V_1}{V_2}=1$ then both will condense simultaneously.

If only one of them condenses ($\frac{V_1}{V_2}\neq 1$) then we have the simple situation in which the condensate is not a mixture of liquids but is only one kind of liquid.

If both of them condense simultaneously ($\frac{V_1}{V_2}=1$) the question becomes complicated. The two gases may or may not condense on the same nucleation site. The question, under what conditions they may condense on the same nucleation site, belongs to chemistry, and I don't know the answer. Even if they do, then the vapor pressure at which each component of the liquid will remain in equilibrium depends in general on their relative composition in condensate, so calculations become messy.